# RTTI and virtual functions in c++ . Is the implementation approach of gcc necessary?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, rtti

While trying to understand the inner workings of virtual function and RTTI, I observed the subsequent fact by examining the gcc compiler:

When structs or classes have a virtual function than the space occupied by them get's expanded by preciding them with a pointer that determines their type.

More over and worse, when multiple inheritance is active, each substructure adds another pointer. So e.g. a structure as:

```
struct C: public A, public B{...}
```

creates a structure with the data of A and B plus two pointers.
That is memory and efficiency consuming.
The question is if that is needed.

I don't have experience in working with those arguments but the logic thougths that I would like to ask if are buggy are as follows:

a) when we declare a variable of a certain struct type we know it's type. So when we have to pass that variable by value to another function we know it's type and we may pass it as a plain old structure along with an extra value indicating it's type ( I mean the compiler should take care of that).

b) When we pass a struct by reference or by pointer we know again the starting type and we may pass a pointer along with an extra value indicating the type.

In order to assign a struct passed by value to a narrower type we have just to take the necessary subpart (offsets calculation).
In order to change to a narrower pointer we have to adjust the pointer and change the extra value indicating the type accordingly.

So along that line of thoughs, we need to have the extra type indication only when passing called arguments between functions on the stack and it isn't needed to save them in each struct.

What am am I missing ? 
The only case that I see would need the type information stored along with the data is when we use a Union and we need to save any kind of a certain specific list of structures but tha is any case resolved by other means. 
So the question is if dynamic type information is needed besides when passing arguments between functions, and if and where eventually that is mandated by the standard.

Comment: b) Is a worse option. You've essentially doubled the size of pointers as they now they all need to keep type information in case they're passed to another function. Instead of doing that RTTI adds one pointer to the object being pointed to, a pointer that's needed to implement virtual functions anyways.

Comment: also this gets worse when you get into looking into virtual inheritance, though most people run away from that (with good reason)

Comment: How would your proposal handle `std::vector<BaseClass*>` which contains multiple types inherited from `BaseClass`?

Comment: @RossRidge It is true that pointers get bigger. The question is if class instances are less than pointers or pointers less than class instances. Virtual functions do have all the necessary information any way because that is given by the type part of the pointer or by the compiler directly.

Comment: Your question was whether it was necessary and the answer to that question is, strictly speaking, no.  You could instead double the size of pointers so they both point to the object and the type of that object, like what your suggested alternative effectively results in. However this would end up consuming far more memory and end hurting performance because pointers are now twice as big and twice as costly to copy.

Answer (score 1):

> What am am I missing ?

rtti and `dynamic_cast` need to be able to deduce the layout of the object from any one of its interfaces.

How will you do that unless each interface encapsulates a pointer to this information?

example of RTTI:

```
struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };  // virtual base class

struct B : A {}; // derived polymorphic class

A* p = new B();
std::cout << typeid(*p).name() << std::endl;
```

Exercise for reader:

1. Which class's name gets printed?
2. Why?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? rtti doesn't depends (from what I have recently understood on virtual functions). So when a struct with virtual function is passed both the data and it's type should be are passed. So any Dynamic_cast has will have the same information that had if the data was inside the structure and part of it.

Comment: @Richard_Hodges Referring to the code: As A* p is set to a B, that means that in the implementation supposed by me, p is a "pointer" holding both the address of B and the type of it. The compiler knows that it is creating a B and so passes a couple holding the address of B and the type of B. Finally when std::cout get's printed, it will print the typeid of B ( as I understand the implementation ). That should be what is expected.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis now suppose the assignment happened in one translation unit and the type query happened in another. Let's also assume that B is not defined in the translation unit where the query happens. It still needs to work, no matter what object type p is pointing to (provided it's derived from A). From this it follows that every A and everything derived from it must carry information (accessible from the A interface) about the type.

Comment: The type query gets a pointer and a type anyway so it knows what to do. The definition of B may be somewhere where will be created the code holding the methods of B. The A* has two choices to call a non virtual function and in that case it has to convert between B* to A* adding an offset if A was the second element of a multipleInheritance definition. If A has to access a virtual method than it has the index to it ( that is the same for all the list of derived classes - when equal ). So it calls it using the vtable of B (using thus the type of B) and the relative vtable index

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis not sure what to say. In person it would be simple to explain why it is like it is, with paper and pencil. On a iPad it's not so easy. The vtable and type info pointer (usually the first item in the vtable) are both necessary. If they were not, I can assure you that they would not be there. The maintainers of gcc are bright people. The thousands of people who have worked on this toolset have not missed an easy performance win. You do not have some insight that everyone else has missed.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis ah now I see what you're missing. You think the pointer has two parts, a type part and an address part. This is an error. The pointer to A is only an address. Any object with an A interface must have a means of getting to all other interfaces (e.g., B). This information is available from A's vtable. It's not encoded into the pointer value. That would be wasteful because the pointer. Would then be bigger than necessary.

Comment: Yes I am supposing to double the size of a pointer (to struct having virtual methods). From my experience pointers or references are used as temporary holders for calculation purposes. I mean that in a program there are usually an array of 100.000 data "records" and some limited pointers to iterate over them. So the idea should be simpler than breaking compatibility with "old type" struct. So I still suppose there may be other reasons for wich the current approach was selected as the best one.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis performance and memory efficiency (which translates to performance). In any real-world performance-critical game or server application, there will be (tens of) thousands of pointers in play at any one moment - doubling their size not only causes cache misses it also means two loads and two stores for every pointer load or store... and the loss of a free register... all for something you rarely do. dynamic_cast is (or should be!) an infrequent operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think, following code will explain it all:

```
// in header.h
struct Base {
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

// in impl.cpp
void work(Base* b) {
    b->foo();
}
```

Assume the code above gets compiled into a C++ library. Never touched afterwards.

Now, some time later, we write following code:

```
#include <header.h>
struct D : Base {
    void foo() { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

void my() {
    D* d = new D;
    work(d);
}
```

As you see, we can't possibly pass any type to `work()` - when it was compiled, `D` didn't even exist! The elegance of virtual functions through pointers to virtual function table - this is what those pointers are - is that above design is allowed.

Comment: When you pass the pointer d the compiler knows that d is a (D*) and so it has to pass the pointer the the plain old Base struct and the type of D (so two data a void* and a typeid or similar). So when work executes knows what is the actual class of *d because the compiler generated the type of it and sended it to function "work".

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, again - code for `work`, full and complete, was generated before `D` existed at all. `work` can not have any knowledge of `D` whatsoever.

Comment: It is the compiler that should take care of sending for each structure passed between functions (when these have virtual pointers) besides the address of the mere data the typeid. The Work function has to be compiled with the same compiler in order to "know the trick" and get and use both informations.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, are you saying that the same pointer could be detached from the object and just used along whenever the object itself is used? But what would be the benefit?

Comment: So basically you're proposing to tack on a hidden parameter when calling the function? Telling it "I'm a Base" or "I'm a D"?

Comment: This wouldn't hold at all in a `std::vector<Base*>`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, telling it 'I am A D' will not work, since `work()` has no idea what `D` is. Potentially, using a hidden parameter of exactly the same semantic as vptr would work, but I fail to see the benefit. And obviously, your example with `vector` will have to hold this hidden pointer as well.

Comment: I agree with you @SergeyA I was targeting my question toward george

Comment: Yes the space occupied on the stack is exactly the same but only on stack. For out of stack structures things are as are in C.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Regarding any pointer to struct with virtual functions, the pointer is really a couple holding address and type. And I am not proposing, I am asking if such an implementation is standard compliant or there is something that I miss.

Comment: So yes, you effectively want the same thing, but detach vptr from the actual structure. Like I said, there are no benefits to it, just extra headache for compiler.

Comment: The advantage is huge for out of stack struct and as usually struct are passed by reference or pointer the pointer is used to iterate and is 1 while the elements are many and stay there for ever consuming space. Moreover we could add object encapsulation to old code without changing anything.